# IE removes CHECKED attribute during animation

Tags: jquery, internet-explorer

I have some radio buttons inside a `<div>` container which I show and hide via jQuery effect.  When the container hides in Firefox, the radio buttons are fine and the values reappear when the container reappears.  However, in IE, the radio buttons first clear the checked radio button and then hides.  You can see it happen in fact.

I also know that it is clearing both the UI (checked) button appearance and the CHECKED attribute of the tag because looking for a radio button in the container with a CHECKED attribute fails to return anything.

Has anyone experienced this problem before?

Answer (score 4):

If the content is modified in IE, you'll need to [reset the defaultChecked attribute](http://webbugtrack.blogspot.com/2007/11/bug-299-setattribute-checked-does-not.html) (case maters in IE!)

Comment: That doesn't seem right. Why would adding an effect make a difference? Everything works when using:

$('#' + sectionId).hide();

but not

$('#' + sectionId).hide('blind',{},1000);